# How to get objects from database by ids

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, typeorm

In my case, i accepts in my request a list of ids for example `[1,2,3]`, how to get only objects with this ids from my database with using `typeorm` and `querybuilder`?

i try this:

```js
if(dto.customersIds){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(dto.customersIds, ids => {
        res.where(`customer.id = ${ids}`);
    })
}
```

but this not work and get me only object with last id in array.

can somebody tell me how to get objects by ids?

thanks for any help

Comment: Is "res" the customer's repository?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(dto.customersIds, ids => {
    res.where(`customer.id = ${ids}`);
})
```

with:

```js
res.whereInIds(dto.customersIds);
```

I assume `res` is created from `createQueryBuilder`